# Given rearrangements A and B, compute P such that A[P] == B

Tags: python, numpy

If `A` and `B` are two arrays corresponding to two orderings of the same (distinct) elements, there is a unique indexing array `P` such that `A[P]` is equal to `B`.  For example, if `A` and `B` are

```
A = ['b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'a']
B = ['a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'e']
```

then the desired `P` is

```
P = [4, 3, 1, 0, 2]
```

Does numpy (or standard Python) have a function for computing such a `P`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Numpy

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(['b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'a'])
B = np.array(['a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'e'])

P = np.empty(len(A), int)
P[B.argsort()] = A.argsort()
```

Comment: Nice.  This will be *much* faster than @g4ur4v's answer when the number of elements is large: O(n*log(n)) vs O(n**2).

Answer (score 4):

Using standard python

```
>>> A = ['b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'a']
>>> B = ['a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'e']
>>> P = [ A.index(i) for i in B ]
>>> P
[4, 3, 1, 0, 2]
```